# How to make a line through text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text

Using the `TextStyle()` class in Flutter, how can I strike through an old price?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

To apply strikethrough decoration to a `Text` widget directly:

```
Text('\$8.99', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough))
```

You can also style separate spans of a paragraph by using the [`RichText`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget, or the [`Text.rich()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html) constructor.

Based on [this example code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/09276bea258737e11b109e227f70eac94a4e1691/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart#L106), to show a discounted price:

### `RichText()`

```
new RichText(
  text: new TextSpan(
    text: 'This item costs ',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      new TextSpan(
        text: '\$8.99',
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        ),
      ),
      new TextSpan(
        text: ' \$3.99',
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

### `Text.rich()`

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(
    text: 'This item costs ',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      new TextSpan(
        text: '\$8.99',
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        ),
      ),
      new TextSpan(
        text: ' \$3.99',
      ),
    ],
 ),
)
```

Comment: This can also be applied directly to a Text widget via its style attribute (see other answer by Tree). `Text(s, style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough))`

Comment: Giving an example should be followed only after the mention of attribute in question. Examples are helpful for Newbie programmers to understand How to use it but to seasoned programmers just the attribute is a hint, good enough. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @sud007 I gave a full example because the question specifically asked, "... how can I strike through _an old price_." (Emphasis added.) I'll improve this answer and call out the strikethrough `TextDecoration` upfront.

Comment: @ChanceSnow My only emphasis was to make a point in favor of SOF as a community for solutions and not handhold coding. But anyway, any support provided here is selfless, takes time to post and hence much appreciated, #peace

Comment: You can do it also with rich text !

Comment: How to achieve a diagonal strikethrough. coz this simply a horizontal through a text. is there built in option for that or should we create a custom widget with the line and a text stacked.

Comment: @DhananjayGavali I would use the [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget with the [`foregroundPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/foregroundPainter.html) parameter to produce that effect.

Answer (score 88):

```
style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
```

Comment: how to make it to have rounded ends?

Comment: @PaulGrei Do you mean that the underline's line caps are rounded?

Comment: @ChanceSnow no. A lineThrough that has rounded ends.

Answer (score -24):

i use this

```
Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        "sample text"
      ),
      Divider(color: Colors.red,)
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: To expand on @AlekseyPotapov’s point, this is especially important for old questions with established answers. Could you explain why your approach might be preferable over @Chance-Snow‘s accepted answer from a couple of years ago?

Comment: Instead of a column, if you use a Stack, it could be a solution, but the real solution is the one marked