# Flutter strikethrough checkbox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _isSelected = !_isSelected;
    });
  },
  child: Container(
    child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                border: _isSelected
                    ? null
                    : Border.all(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        width: 1.0,
                      )),
            width: widget.size,
            height: widget.size,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: _isSelected ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
                fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      _isSelected
          ? Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            )
          : Container(),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

Hi, I'm creating an application on the Flutter «ToDo List». I ran into a problem with the design of a strikethrough checkbox. The fact is that my strikethrough goes beyond the content, and I need it to be only on the content. The pictures will be more clear

This is what I need:

[image]

I get it like this:

[image]

I attached a piece of code from the custom_checkbox.dart file that I wrote myself. Likewise, I think it is clear that it is used like this:

```
               Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        CustomCheckbox(
                          text: "Packing things",
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        CustomCheckbox(
                          text: "Buy milk",
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        CustomCheckbox(
                          text: "Run 3 miles",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: how about using `strikethrough` from Text? Seems you are creating separate widget for the line?

Comment: Bro, I don't want strikethrough text, I want a strip that goes on top of the checkbox and text. Look at the picture more closely.

Answer (score 1):

In the code, your using a container with a heigh of 1 to simulate a border to put a line on a text. This is the worse way to do it.

If you put a container in a row like you've done, the container will take the width of the row. So, this is normal that your container has this width.

If you want a strikethrough text you simply have to add to your TextStyle:

```
decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough
```

So you should have:

```
Text(
    widget.text,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: _isSelected ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
      fontSize: 14,
      decoration: _isSelected ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null
    ),
),
```

Please make more research before asking a question that is answered a tone of time on stackoverflow.

[stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722987/how-to-make-a-line-through-text-in-flutter)

Comment: Bro, I don't want strikethrough text, I want a strip that goes on top of the checkbox and text. Look at the picture more closely. I appreciate everyone's time, I've seen the article about the strikethrough text, it's about something else.

Comment: Damn, this design is as terrible as I though it was what you do not want ! Well it is going to be hard because a Stack inside a Row doesn't have a defined width until you determine one !